# Local tunnel for accessing Grafana on localhost

Tags: macos, ssh, debian, grafana, ssh-tunnel

I just installed Grafana server on my Debian server that I'm accessing via SSH. I'm having a problem while creating a local tunnel from my university server to my local machine so I can access it from my browser. When I try to create a local tunnel I run into this issue:

```
bind [::1]:3000: Cannot assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3000
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Command for local tunel creating that I'm using:

```
ssh -NL 3000:localhost:3000 hostname@server_address
```

*grafana.ini* file:
[grafana.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYgPO.jpg)

output of `service grafana-server status`: [grafana-server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpLR3.jpg)

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Why `macos` tag ? 2) Can you check if port `3000` is already used using `netstat` ?

Comment: Because almost all solution I have found for this were done on Windows in Putty, which is not the case for me. Checked ports in use, 3000 used by grafana-server.

Comment: So you are using macos (local machine) to access Grafana server (Debian) ? Haev you checked port 3000 on macos ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Port 3000 is free on macOS. I have tried other ports on both machines and it gives me the same output.

Comment: Is `ssh hostname@server_address` working fine ?

Comment: Just solved that. Local tunnel was not needed here. The issue was that I was not using university vpn and could not load its address. After I turned on the vpn and typed server_address:3000 into in browser, it loaded Graphana login page. Thanks for help tho!